# How to build a small set of steps/stairs

Tags: wood, stairs, steps

I just had a paver patio installed and had the builder re-install the old wooden steps that he removed to do the work. We did this as a cost savings measure since stone steps would've doubled the price of the project. Now with this nice new patio, our old steps look pretty decrepit. I would like to replace the steps I have with something similar, maybe using a composite decking material if possible both for looks and for longevity. Can anyone provide some insight for a do-it-yourselfer? There are only about four steps/stairs that make up the unit.

Comment: What is the total height (grade to landing)?

Comment: @Tester101 - I don't have the measurements with me at the moment but I'll update the question when I get home.

Comment: A picture with dimension might be useful, if you are looking for a very specific answer.

Comment: most home centers sell precut stringers which is typically the tough part for a novice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local home improvement store may have prefab/precut stair case parts for decks and they about the size you mention (3-4 steps).  You can purchase the stringers, and treads and attach them in place of your old stairs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Prefab Stairs - you could search google
for "Prefab Stairs", there should be something for your area.

Or Make your own deck steps like the following:  ([DIY LINK](http://homes.ninemsn.com.au/diy/homeimprovement/8200094/deck-steps))

I would recommend that you search for "Landscaping Stairs: in google for some great ideas!
You can have a look with the following search - [Google Image Search](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=landscaping%20stairs&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=GoAqUOKaOcqGhQey6IC4Cw&ved=0CE8QsAQ)